# Unidentified SMD Component

Tags: identification, surface-mount

A component burnt up on my remote control receiver and I want to identify it.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Yikes, I think it is time for a new one =-D

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to just identify the single smd component and replace it with one off of a salvaged board. I know the entire receiver is cheap but my location and timeframe has lead me searching for a solution other than buying a entire new one then waiting for it ect. I like to do things the hard way I guess. Thank you for your email information and the speedy reply.

Comment: The problem is that there's about half a million different parts in the SOT23-6 package, everything from regulators to ADCs to micros to radios to good ol' transistors, so unless there's someone here with the same unit who can do a cross reference on the id No. (those things are too small for real part numbers) and has a rough idea what it's supposed to do, then I'm afraid you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

This board is in pretty bad shape.  There are two obvious failures, and these tend to ripple downstream and cause other problems:

[image]

It looks to me that these are for power regulation.  The corroded part may be the same as the orange tantalum capacitor next to it.  If so, they could be input and output caps to a voltage regulator.  And the 6-pin (destoyed) IC could be that regulator.

I think it's time to replace it!